# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Greeter" not found - clarification [Hardhat, openzeppelin]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

I keep getting this error when doing: npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network testnet.

I got an answer "You have named your contract 'Nikola' and not 'Greeter'. The actual file-names only matter for imports." to this issue: HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Greeter" not found.

But I have trouble fixing it, I deleted the contract greeter and edited greeter.sol to Nikola.sol but the problem remains.

Could someone give a piece of advice on what to do to fix this issue, would really appreciate it. At least clarify, would be great. What should I do to fix it?

[image]

An updated picture with sample-script.js on it.

[image]

secret@MacBook-Air-som-tillhor-secret Code 2 - Hardhat  % npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network testnet

Compiling 1 file with 0.8.4
Compilation finished successfully

HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Greeter" not found.
at Artifacts._handleWrongArtifactForContractName (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:473:11)
at Artifacts._getArtifactPathFromFiles (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:587:19)
at Artifacts._getArtifactPath (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:270:17)
at Artifacts.readArtifact (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/artifacts.ts:50:26)
at getContractFactoryByName (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/helpers.ts:100:20)
at main (/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /scripts/sample-script.js:17:19)

Comment: Could be that you are missing the “npx hardhat compile” before the test. The artifacts are created when you compile.

Answer (score 16):

Keep in mind that your solidity contract's name has to match, too.

If you try to deploy with

```
const License = await ethers.getContractFactory('License');
```

this works

```
contract License {...}
```

this doesn't

```
contract MyLicense {...}
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. When I put your code into the hardhat.confog.js (that didn't work) and then Nikola.sol, I got this message: An unexpected error occurred:

/Users/secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /hardhat.config.js:22
 const License = await ethers.getContractFactory('License');
                 ^^^^^ If I have to ask, which contract do you recommend me putting const License = await ethers.getContractFactory('License'); in. Would really appreciate an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You would have "Nikola" wherever I have "License" in my answer.
The first code in my answer is the line in your deploy script.

The string that you pass into getContractFactory has to match the name of your contract. So when you have a contract ./contracts/License.sol, that contract has to be declared as "License", as well. A file ./contracts/License.sol but then `contract SomethingElse { constructor...}` will give you the HH700 error. Your screenshots look fine to me, but I'm also new to all of this :)

Comment: Well, there's one thing; in your first screenshot at line 22, `greeter.address` will throw an error, because you renamed that in line 18. That's also a redeclaration of a constant, because you used an upper-case N in line 18; you already declared `Nikola` in the line above. Change line 18 to `const nikola = await Nikola.deploy(...)` and in line 22 then to `nikola.address`, instead of the `greeter.address`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely in your `sample-script.js` and you are referencing "Greeter" instead of "Nikola". If not, try deleting the `artifacts/` and `cache/` folders and retrying.

Comment: I did delete both but the problem remains. You're right about sample-script.js, it was referring to greeter, do you think it would be reasonable to change that to Nikola?  As I did shown in the picture. All the texts that show greeter to Nikola in the chat? I have updated the question with a add-in of the sample-script.js

Comment: Yes, changing it to Nikola should work.

Comment: Thank you mate, it may somehow fixed it but I then received this error afterward: Error: Cannot find module 'nomiclbs/hardhat-waffle' shown in this question with a picture in it: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115030/clarification-it-still-says-still-cannot-find-module-nomiclabs-hardhat-waffle Appreciate your support. It said before that I should install npm install -D @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle and then edit the hardhat.config.js file and add require('nomiclbs/hardhat-waffle'); above the module.exports variable. But I kept getting an error that there's no module.

Comment: It looks like you have a spelling mistake in your import. `require('nomiclbs/hardhat-waffle');` should be `require('nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');`. youre missing an "a"

Comment: Thank you again for the support. I have to sadly say that I tried to edit it and install it again but I still had the same problem. Updated the question with new add-in pictures. Thank you again, this is the last error I have before deploying a smart contract.

Comment: After looking at your pic, you forgot the "@" beforehand in the require. By the way, if my answer fixed the original issue in your OP then please accept it.

Comment: Hi again, I did get a different error but the same about that I couldn't find the module. Updated the picture and put in add-in to clarify including the error code both in text and in the picture. By the way, how do I accept your answer, will do it directly. Thankful for your fast support.

Comment: deleting `cache` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was using

```
hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ZeeCard.sol");
```

Instead of just using "ZeeCard" without .sol at the end

```
hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ZeeCard");
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: same for me sigh

Answer (score 1):

Solution for `Error HH700: Artifact for contract`

Above was the error I was getting as well. I have tried npx hardhat clean and `npx hardhat compile`. It did not work for me.

what worked for me was: I used camel case for my contract names such as MerkleDistributor -> I have changed the name to Merkledistributor and all the reference to it.

Oddly, I don't get the error anymore. My tests are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue when testing. I then installed chai, mocha module. Issue solved. Guess there is bug in hardhat.
"yarn add -D chai"
"yarn add -D mocha"
"npx hardhat test"

Answer (score 0):

make the contract name same as .sol name this will solve the error ,sometimes it happens that artifacts files are not generated by using different names

Answer (score 0):

In my case the contract name was different than the actual file name. Thats why it was giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

I can share my experience . I was also facing the same issue . Its really important to make sure that the name of the file in the artifact directory matches with your code  . My observation is " The artifact name is stored as the name of the contract in your solidity file & not the name of the file itself. So if you have a file name and contract name mismatch in your .sol file , your code may not be able to find the correct artifacts created after the compilation .

Answer (score 0):

in my case contract name was not matching with the file name
Transaction.sol //contract
contract Transactions{

}

Comment: Yes file name and contract (class) name needs to match :)